# Running two web applications on same port?

Tags: java, web-applications, webserver, jetty

We have two different Java web apps named foo.war and bar.war and we want to deploy these on Jetty server

Jetty is running on 8080 port on the machine

Is it possible simultaneously run two apps on same port ? If no what are the alternatives to run multiple web apps on same jetty server

Thanks

Comment: The applications from the wars just need to have a different context-root and this should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run as many web applications as you want in a servlet container. They just need different context roots.

Let's say you have abc.war and def.war. If you deploy both, by default you can access them through `http://localhost:8080/abc` and `http://localhost:8080/def`.

Since this usually looks ugly, it's a good idea to put a reverse proxy in front of your Servlet container. This will allow you to have for example 2 different domains `foobar.com` and `xipbaz.com` that will then be routed to different applications, even if they're all on the same server.

Comment: Or just use the virtualHosts configurations in Jetty to route requests for `foobar.com` to `foo.war` and requests for `xipbaz.com` to `xip.war`