# How to create multi web module application in spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a multi-web module application in spring. Below is the project structure.

```
+-- Parent
|---- Java (Which has the controller, models and views)
|---- resources
|---- webapp
|------ web.xml
|------ jsp 
+-- Purchase (Submodule 1)
|---- Java (Which has the controller, models and views)
|---- resources
|---- webapp
|------ web.xml
|------ jsp 
+-- Sales (Submodule 2)
|---- Java (Which has the controller, models and views)
|---- resources
|---- webapp
|------ web.xml
|------ jsp
```

I want to build purchase (submodule 1) and sales (submodule2) as separate jar or war and add it to the lib of parent and run the application and access the controllers as

```
localhost:8080/parent
localhost:8080/purchase
localhost:8080/sales
```

Could someone let me know the approach that available in spring to achieve the thing it would be helpful

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the benefit of this structure? I think you can separate them in view layer.

Comment: I'm trying to make it as a plug and play module. There are cases that I need only parent & purchase or parent & sales.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? Feature Flagging might be more in line with what you want to achieve. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-feature-flags

Comment: @Dean I'm using spring mvc, I will take a look at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the structure and responsibility for each project, I would suggest modeling it like

**parent**

- **web-service** (only controllers and views, no business logic, delegates to sales and purchase for business logic)
- **sales** (sales business logic - no controllers and views)
- **purchase** (purchase business logic - no controllers and views)

You might have to add additional modules for **utils** / **persistence** / **entities**, depending on your specific requirements.

Regarding building per se, there are a couple of options here, the most widely used bing **maven** and **gradle**. Both of them support structuring an application in parent - child modules. Both of them support adding dependencies for a child module in another child module (so you are able to add dependencies on **sales** and **purchase** in **web-service**).

Both maven and gradle will take care to build all needed dependencies for a given module before building that module (so it is guaranteed that **sales** and **purchase** will be built before **web-service**). Both maven and gradle will fail the build if they are not able to satisfy a dependency.

Comment: I come across this approach, but I need to skip that feature in the final build (war) if that was not part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about the which web server you use. Just set them different context roots. You should take a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008624/7541163